# Two webserver in same instance for different domains

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, lamp, httpd.conf

I am running two web-server in one AWS instance, One Lamp stack apache(a.com) and a Bitnami's apache(b.com). Apache is using port 80 which is my default port and Bitnami is using port 8080. How can I point two domains to the same instance so that it will show up the content for a.com and b.com. And same time the port number shouldn't be visible out side. I tried with virtual-host found out its impossible since I have a separate virtual host file for Bitmani.

Comment: Why not use a single apache server, and different virtual hosts?

Comment: This question is off-topic, advise you go here: http://serverfault.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Both servers should serve the same content using same website but with different virtual host configuration files ??

Instead of using two webservers, increase the cpu and core capacity and enable worker MPM and increase process count and use virtual host configuration with two different ports.